# Looking for close value to zero for a particular id

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for the nearest value to zero for a particular id

My input is

```
    tech_Id time_diff
    1000      100
    1000      200
    1000      -50
    1000      -10
    1001      100
    1001      200
    1001       50
    1001       10
    1002      -50
    1002      -10
    1003      130
    1003     -140
    1003      -2
```

expected output

```
tech_Id time_diff
1000     -10
1001      10
1002     -10
1003      -2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Why is there 50 for 1001 in your sample output?

Comment: its a mistake.Edited to 10..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find min of absolute value of time diff.

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join (
    select tech_id, min(abs(time_diff)) as time_diff
    from your_table
    group by tech_id
    ) t2 on t1.tech_id = t2.tech_id and abs(t1.time_diff) = t2.time_diff;
```